# How can I make these elements line up correctly using CSS?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

Here is how my menu looks right now:
[image]

Here is how I want it to look:
[image]

Right now I have the following css:

```
#menu
{
    position:relative;
    width: 940px;   
    height:90px;

}

#menuItem
{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}

.titleText
{
    float: right;
    color:#209202;
    font-size:22px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-weight:bold;
}
```

And the following HTML:

```
<div id="titleBar">

        <div id="menu">
            <div id="menuItem">


<ul class="tabs">
    <li><a href="/dashboard/">

        <img alt="Dashboard" src="/Content/Images/Dashboard_green.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/placements/">

        <img alt="Place Accounts" src="/Content/Images/Place_Accounts_white.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/messages">

        <img alt="Messages" src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/reports">

        <img alt="Reports" src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
    <li><a href="/admin">

        <img alt="Admin" src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png" />
        </a>
    </li>
</ul>

            </div>
              <div class="titleText">

        Dashboard

        </div> 
        </div>

    </div>
```

I've tried a million different things to get titleText 40px from the right hand side and 50px from the top, and having the tabs floating 40px from the left bottom, but everything I try gets me close but then fails to work in IE7 for some reason.

menu represents the whole grey bar area.  menuItem is the tabs.  titleText is the green word that says "Dashboard".

I should I style menuItem, menu, and titleText so it displays like the correct image below and still works in IE7?

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.  I've been trying at this blindly for awhile.

Comment: do you have any css put on the li and ul tags at all as well?

Answer (score 1):

this is very easy, but requires a small change to your html, because you'll need place the Dashboard text above the menu.

you need to think about this kind of code:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
    <h1>Dashboard</h1> 
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/dashboard/"><img alt="Dashboard" src="/Content/Images/Dashboard_green.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/placements/"><img alt="Place Accounts" src="/Content/Images/Place_Accounts_white.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/messages"><img alt="Messages" src="/Content/Images/Messages_white.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/reports"><img alt="Reports" src="/Content/Images/Reports_white.png" /></a></li>
        <li><a href="/admin"><img alt="Admin" src="/Content/Images/Admin_white.png" /></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

this'll allow you to make your CSS a lot easier, as you can simply `float` the `h1` to the `right` (declare it as a `block`) and the `ul` to the `left`

after this, you can simply add the needed margins paddings and other stying.

Answer (score 0):

I would use either absolute positioning (left, top) or floats (padding-left, padding-top, float:left); not a combination of both.

By the way: That applies not only to the menu but also to the title on the right side.

Answer (score 0):

Remove position:absolute from #menuitem, and add a top padding to #menu

```
#menu
{
    position:relative;
    width: 940px;       
    height:40px;  /* remember that height + padding = total height */
    padding-top:50px; /* adjust as necessary to push the tabs and text down */
}

#menuItem
{
    padding-left: 50px;
    float: left;
    width: 600px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the `titleText` div, you should be able to just give it margin...

```
.titleText
{
    float: right;
    color:#209202;
    font-size:22px;
    font-style:italic;
    font-family:Georgia;
    font-weight:bold;
    margin: 50px 40px 0 0;
}
```

in case you didn't already know, when you list off 4 parameters for margin, they are designated as follows...

margin: TOP RIGHT BOTTOM LEFT

As to Joel Potter's answer, I would have to agree, take away the absolute positioning from `#menuItem`, but also, you then do NOT need `position: relative` designated to `#menu` anymore.

Its only purpose seemed to be keeping `#menuItem` relative to `#menu`, but without it being absolutely positioned now there is no need for it.